# Unable to access images from public folder with webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

- This issue seems related to webpack config, as when we serve webpack then bundle/virtual copy is created for development environment, and because of images are not present its showing broken icon.
- I am unable to access images from public folder in a react component.
- My existing react application is now integrated with webpack, everything works fine excepts images.

I want to use images using **url** not by using **import** statement.

**Expected way:** `<img src={"/images/logo.png"} alt="logo" className={classes.logo} />`

**Not Expected:** `import logo from '../../../public/images/logo.png'`

following is my application structure,
Please let me know what loader or configuration or any better way is present for dev & prod environment?

[image: ss]

Here is my webpack configuration for development.

[image: ss2]

Thanks in advance
:)

Comment: You are setting the image `src` attribute correctly from what I can tell. What is the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese
when we serve webpack app, its create virtual copy of bundle, and images are not present in that bundle. thant's why its showing broken images.

Comment: So are the images not located in "public/images"? Or is this *some* webpack issue where we need to see what your code/config is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/yourPath.jpg'} />
```

Or this should also work

```
<img src={window.location.origin + '/yourPath.jpg'} />
```

Comment: When we serve webpack app, its create virtual copy of bundle & run dev server, and images are not present in that bundle. thant's why its showing broken images. so its not working like this way.